# sort a matrix based on another matrix in r

Tags: r, sorting, matrix

I have two matrices:

`A = matrix(c(2,1,3,6,4,3,8,1,6,2,9,5), ncol=4)`
`B = matrix(c(20,10,30,60,40,30,80,10,60,20,90,50), ncol=4)`

Now, I have sorted the matrix A by rows:

`A_sorted=t(apply(A,1,sort))`

`2    2    6    8`
`1    1    4    9`
`3    3    5    6`

Now, I want to sort the B matrix in the same order as of A, so that the new matrix 'B_sorted' would be:

`20   20   60   80`
`10   10   40   90`
`30   30   50   60`

I have found a similar answer from the past [Sort one matrix based on another matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11108713/sort-one-matrix-based-on-another-matrix) but the codes from the answer do not work with a matrix of different dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t(sapply(1:NROW(A), function(i) B[i,][order(A[i,])]))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   20   20   60   80
#[2,]   10   10   40   90
#[3,]   30   30   50   60
```

Answer (score 2):

We can loop through the sequence of rows with `for` loop and assign the rows of 'B' based on the `order` of 'A' rows

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(A))) B[i,] <- B[i,][order(A[i,])]
B
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   20   20   60   80
#[2,]   10   10   40   90
#[3,]   30   30   50   60
```

Comment: @user2797174  `apply/sapply/lapply` are all loops.  If you want to check some comparisons, you can look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933130/apply-vs-for-loop-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393658/lapply-vs-for-loop-performance-r)

Answer (score 2):

You can create the index that sort the matrix by row with `order(row(A), A)` and then reorder the original matrix with it; later on add dimension to sorted data with `matrix`:

```
matrix(B[order(row(A), A)], byrow = TRUE, ncol = ncol(B))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   20   20   60   80
#[2,]   10   10   40   90
#[3,]   30   30   50   60
```